# React Router Removes server prefix (Reverse Proxy)

Tags: reactjs, nginx, react-router, reverse-proxy

I am trying to run a React Application behind a reverse proxy server that has a prefix(say `root-prefix`) and secondary prefix(say `subdirectory/path`).

The final URL is of form `https://myserver.com/root-prefix/subdirectory/path`

I have added `basename` for subdirectory:

```js
 <BrowserRouter basename="/subdirectory/path">
                <Header />
                    <Switch>
                        <Route
                            path="/componentA"
                            component={componentA}
                        />
                        <Route
                            path="/componentB"
                            component={componentB}
                        />
                    </Switch>
                <Footer />
 </BrowserRouter>
```

Server URL: `https://myserver.com/root-prefix/subdirectory/path`: This renders a path with Header and Footer without Main content.

When I hit specific a component it renders but is the of form `https://myserver.com/subdirectory/path/componentA` (Note `root-prefix` is removed.)

My `nginx.conf`

```
http {

server {

location ^~ /subdirectory/path {
      # proxy_pass ${upstream}; # Getting 502: Bad Gateway
      absolute_redirect off;
      add_header Access-Control-Expose-Headers "Origin";
      add_header Access-Control-Allow-Methods "GET,POST,PUT,DELETE";
      try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }
}

}
```

Is React Router removing `root-prefix` internally. If so, what is the approach for allowing `root-prefix` for all components.

Note: Prefixing `root-prefix` in `location` of Nginx gives 404 for the entire application.

Comment: were you able to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

you need to include the `root-prefix` in the basename:

```
<BrowserRouter basename="/root-prefix/subdirectory/path">
```

Comment: The server I am working with already creates `/root-prefix`. 
For your solution the URL becomes `https://myserver.com/root-prefix/root-prefix/subdirectory/path`